# Session being closed unexpectedly?

Tags: php, session-timeout

i have a problem with what seems like session timing out and being destroyed, though i currently do not have it set to expire after a certain amount of time, nor do i have the session destroyed anywhere in the code.

Here's what happens in detail,

it's an e-comm site i have 90 % built which also has two payment gateways(PayPal and SecurePay).

first of all, i only have this problem when the website is uploaded to the web host(GoDaddy), i haven't experienced this issue using localhost.

The issue:

1. I can use my site, everything functioning normal, i can choose
   products and checkout successfully through both payment gateways without      issue.
   When i am finished for the day i'll close the browser as per normal.
2. The next morning i will again open the browser and navigate to my
   site. The website has still retained all the session information
   and i can navigate to all my pages without issue, including my shopping cart(my shopping cart
   especially relies on session data to work).
3. During the first time i go to check-out, with **either** payment gateway, everything functions fine until payment
   gateway navigates back to my returnURL, where the session is somehow
   destroyed, all the session data is gone and i am logged out.
4. This only occurs once, specifically the first time i test the
   check-out process after a long period of inactivity. As i log
   back in after the session is destroyed the issue is does not appear to
   happen again, until the next morning.
5. I would also like to add that the return
   urls are quite different for each payment gateway, the PayPal returnURL is a page where
   the order is still being processed and the user can change shipping methods rates, SecurePay returns to a page where the
   transaction is complete and an invoice is genrated, though the result is the same and the session is destroyed when returning from either payment gateway to the return url.

To fix this i was just going to expire the session after 1 hour of session inactivity. But i'm curios why the session would be destroyed only after returning from the payment gateway and not as soon as the page is opened after such period of inactivity?

Comment: Would it be more reliable to base the `shopping cart` on the `user` rather than the session? i.e. The 'user' cookie with the `shopping cart` stored in the database? Or give the `shopping cart` a cookie of its' own? The issue with sessions is that 'go away' after about 30 minutes. The advantage of linking the `cart` to the user, is that even if the user logs out, the `shopping cart` can be retained?

Comment: Well the cart session isn't too big of a concern as i store the cart item ID's in the database when a user is in the checkout process, though i have other general information i need to store from before the user redirects to the payment gateway until when the transaction is complete and i generate the invoice, and that information is getting lost. Though seems maybe sessions are not so reliable for that purpose

Comment: I would be tempted to link  the `cart` to the 'user` when they add the first item to it. The `invoice` would be linked to the `user` and the `cart.`

Comment: Well i create a pending  purchase order and set the invoice number to a session variable which i use in the returnURL to identify the table row to update that database if the transaction is successful or not. I cant reliably store a invoice number through the PalPay gatway as the PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INVNUM can be ignored if the payment is not immediately charged

Comment: I might be able to store the paypal token that's generated for the redirect to the pending purchase order before it redirects and do away with the sessions all together, as it does post me the token again when the transcation is complete, though im not sure if it does if the transaction is declined.. i will check